# Values from Array Only Change Upon First Run of a Function

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner working on a trivia app, and I'm having a heck of a time getting the questions to iterate properly. I've tried things multiple different ways. Here is my current configuration.

The questions are iterated by the `pullQuestions()` function. This function pulls from an array called `question`.

The `pullQuestions()` function is run when the `startbutton` is clicked and when the `submitA` button is clicked. These buttons run either `startGame()` or `submitA()` respectively.

Please note, I have not yet implemented score tracking so the expectation of the submit button is currently limited to pulling the next question.

**Question HTML**

```
        <div id="gameArea" class="questionbox" style="display: none;">
        
            <div class="questionarea">
            
                <h2 id="headerQ">Question Number</h2>
                <p id="content">Question Text</p>
            
            </div>
            
            <div class="answerarea">
                <!-- This can be ignored. This is where my options are but I'm not using them in my code yet -->
        
            </div>
            
            <button id="submitA" class="submitA" onClick="submitA()">Submit</button>
                        
        </div>
```

**startGame() JavaScript** (This works as expected)

```
function startGame(){
    
    document.getElementById("startArea").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("gameArea").style.display = "block";

    question.id = 0;

    pullQuestions();

    console.log("startgame() Executed", question.id);
    console.log(question[0], question[1]);
}
```

**Question Array*** (Set as a Global Variable)

```
function select1() {
    
        if (op1.className == "selectionFalse") {
        document.getElementById("op1").className = "selectionTrue";
        document.getElementById("op2").className = "selectionFalse";
        document.getElementById("op3").className = "selectionFalse";
        document.getElementById("op4").className = "selectionFalse";
    
        console.log("selected1()", "If Condition", op1.className);
        }
    
        else {
        document.getElementById("op1").className = "selectionFalse";
        }   
    }
```

**submitA() JavaScript** (Does not iterate through the Array but does increase the `id` attribute)

```
function submitA() {
    question.id++;
    console.log("submitA() Run)", "Question ID: ", question.id, headerQ, content);
}
```

***pullQuestions() JavaScript** (This is run when the two above functions are run, but I only see results when it runs as part of the `startGame()` function.

```
function pullQuestions() {

if (question.id == 0) {
    document.getElementById("headerQ").innerHTML = question[0].headerQ;
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = question[0].content;

    console.log("pullQuestions() Executed");
    console.log("Variables: ", "headerQ = ", headerQ, "content = ", content); 
    }


if (question.id == 1) {
    document.getElementById("headerQ").innerHTML = question[1].headerQ;
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = question[1].content;

    console.log("pullQuestions() Executed");
    console.log("Variables: ", "headerQ = ", headerQ, "content = ", content);
    }

if (question.id == 2) {
    document.getElementById("headerQ").innerHTML = question[2].headerQ;
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = question[2].content;
    
    console.log("pullQuestions() Executed");
    console.log("Variables: ", "headerQ = ", headerQ, "content = ", content);
        }

}
```

I feel like I'm missing something small, but being that I'm new it's possible I'm approaching this all wrong. Any advice or direction is appreciated.

Comment: This question and its answers is [being discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420935/522444)

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't work for you in the `submitA` button because you forgot to activate the call to in it `pullQuestions`

On the other hand, in `startGame` you did activate `pullQuestions` after you changed the `id`, so it works for you

This is what the function should look like

```
function submitA() {
    question.id++;
    pullQuestions();
    console.log("submitA() Run)", "Question ID: ", question.id, headerQ, content);
}
```